# Pagination appearing twice in URL after rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, rewrite-rules

For my site, I have a custom post type `video` set to appear at at the URL `http://site.url/videos`. It is paginated so that there are 24 videos per archive page. However, I am not using the `single.php` to render a view for the video, I am instead displaying the video's contents via ajax on the archive page when clicked. I allow for linking to specific videos via javascript, which just selects and opens the desired video on page load (via the URL string).

I have rewrite rules in place that allow for `site.url/videos/my-video` to redirect to `index.php?post_type=video` which works great. However, for my paginated videos, I use `single.php` to perform a 301 redirect to the paginated archive page where that individual video is currently located.

My rewrite rule enabling this is as follows:

```
function video_rewrite() {
  add_rewrite_rule('videos/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$', 'index.php?post_type=video&paged=$matches[1]', 'top');`
}
add_action('init', 'video_rewrite');
```

and the redirect code on `single-video.php`

```
$post_id = $post->ID;
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'video',
  'showposts' => -1,
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'order' => 'DESC',
);
$count = 0;
$video_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($video_query->have_posts()) {
  foreach($video_query->posts as $key => $video_post) {
    $count++;
    if ($video_post->ID === $post_id) {
      $post_offset = $key;
    }
  }
}
wp_reset_query();

$posts_per_page = $GLOBALS['videos_posts_per_page'];
$page_number_notrounded = $post_offset / $posts_per_page;
$page_number = round($page_number_notrounded, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
$page_number = $page_number + 1;
if ($page_number > 1) {
  $redirect_url = get_bloginfo('url').'/videos/page/'.$page_number.'/'.$post->post_name;
  $post_link = $redirect_url;
}

wp_redirect($post_link, 301);
exit;
```

For some reason, Wordpress appends pagination twice. Being 301 redirected to `site.url/videos/page/2/my-video` loads the following url: `site.url/videos/page/2/my-video/page/2/`

How can I prevent the pagination from being appended twice?

Comment: What does redirect code look like?

Comment: @Rarst added code above

Comment: Realizing wouldn't work anyways since the first page doesn't have pagination appended to it and would then result in an infinite loop.